# the picture is not displayed and an error occurs when turning off --> Debug Assertion Failed! Expression: is_block_type_valid(header->_block_use)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, debugging, expression

The picture not showing and when I close, error appear. I can’t figure it out, maybe a problem with pointers.

stackoverflow is asking for details, but I have no more details - sorry.
stackoverflow is asking for details, but I have no more details - sorry.
stackoverflow is asking for details, but I have no more details - sorry.
stackoverflow is asking for details, but I have no more details - sorry.
stackoverflow is asking for details, but I have no more details - sorry.

**Menu.h**

```
#include "Picture.h"

class menu
{
    const int menuPictCount;
    picture* menuPicture[];
public:
    menu(sf::RenderWindow& usableArea);
    ~menu();
    void draw();
    void posСorrection();
    void shineButton(sf::Color color);
};
```

---

**Menu.cpp <--------- the problem is here**

````
menu::menu(sf::RenderWindow& usableArea) : menuPictCount(4)
{
    this->menuPicture[this->menuPictCount];

    //background
    this->menuPicture[0] = new picture(usableArea, "image/background/0.png");

    //buttons
    this->menuPicture[1] = new picture(usableArea, "image/menu/newgame.png");
    this->menuPicture[1] = new picture(usableArea, "image/menu/continue.png");
    this->menuPicture[3] = new picture(usableArea, "image/menu/exit.png");
}
menu::~menu()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->menuPictCount; i++) delete this->menuPicture[i];
    delete[] menuPicture;
}
void menu::draw()
{
    for (size_t i = 0; i < this->menuPictCount; i++) this->menuPicture[i]->draw();
}
void menu::posСorrection()
{
    const int buttonsCount = this->menuPictCount - 1;

    if (buttonsCount % 2 == 0)
    {
        int indexCenterOver = buttonsCount / 2;
        int indexCenterUnder = indexCenterOver + 1;
        this->menuPicture[indexCenterOver]->putCenterOver();
        this->menuPicture[indexCenterUnder]->putCenterUnder();

        for (size_t i = indexCenterOver - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            this->menuPicture[i]->putOverObj(*this->menuPicture[i + 1]);
        }
        for (size_t i = indexCenterUnder + 1; i <= buttonsCount; i++)
        {
            this->menuPicture[i]->putUnderObj(*this->menuPicture[i - 1]);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        const int indexCenter = buttonsCount / 2 + 1;

        this->menuPicture[indexCenter]->putCenter();

        for (size_t i = indexCenter - 1; i > 0; i--)
        {
            this->menuPicture[i]->putOverObj(*this->menuPicture[i + 1]);
        }
        for (size_t i = indexCenter + 1; i <= buttonsCount; i++)
        {
            this->menuPicture[i]->putUnderObj(*this->menuPicture[i - 1]);
        }
    }
}
void menu::shineButton(sf::Color color)
{
    /*for (size_t i = 0; i <= this->buttons.GetCount(); i++)
    {
        if (this->buttons.GetElement(i)->data.trackContainsCursor())
            if (this->buttons.GetElement(i)->data.getColor() != color)
            {
                this->buttons.GetElement(i)->data.setColor(color);
            }
        if (!this->buttons.GetElement(i)->data.trackContainsCursor())
            if (this->buttons.GetElement(i)->data.getColor() == color)
            {
                this->buttons.GetElement(i)->data.setColor(color);
            }
    }*/
} ```


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uNY8B.png
````

Comment: `this->menuPicture[this->menuPictCount];` does not allocate any space.  It doesn't do anything at all.

Comment: but if I need to initialize the array only in the constructor implementation?

Comment: You don't have an array, you have a pointer-to-pointer-to-picture.  You need to allocate space for it (using `new`).  Better still, get rid of raw pointers and use smart pointers and standard containers instead.

Comment: Note: `delete[] menuPicture;` only deleted the array of pointers. It did not `delete` the objects that were dynamically allocated and placed in the array. Important note: There is no need to dynamically allocate anything here. You know `menuPicture` is size 4, you you can use a plain old array of `picture`s or a `std::array`.  Smurf this. I'm going to write a non- answer.

Comment: Never mind Looks like chwala's covering this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of

`picture* menuPicture[];`

use

`std::vector<std::unique_ptr<picture>> menuPicture;`

And in `menu` constructor instead of doing this:

`this->menuPicture[this->menuPictCount];`

do this:

`this->menuPicture.resize(this->menuPictCount);`

Edit:
Of course remove also `delete`s from destructor. `std::vector` and `std::unique_ptr` will clean up after themselves.

If number of pictures in menu is constant (like in your constructor) you can change `menuPicture` declaration to:

`std::array<std::unique_ptr<picture>, 4> menuPicture;`

but then you can't call resize on it.